# javascript doesn't load unless I refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I've got some jquery in `$(document).ready()`, but this jquery code doesn't run on my page unless I refresh the page. Then it works on every subsequent refresh. Why is this the case?

I'm just putting in javascript and html tags but I'm working in a rails app, not sure if that complicates things.

Comment: Share the relevant bits of code please?

Comment: Are you using `turbolinks` ?

Comment: yeah I am. Is that why?

Comment: Turbolinks version?

Comment: my turbolinks version is 5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your turbolinks version, you have to use the right syntax to override document load event. For turbolinks 5:

instead of

```
$(document). ready(function () {
....
})
```

Use

```
var documentready = function(){

}
$(document). on('turbolinks:load',  documentready);
```

This will gracefully fall back to document ready event when refreshing.

Why is this necessary?

Turbolinks binds location changes (like clicking links)  and uses Ajax to load the partial. The document IS NOT LOADED. Also, it manipulates browser's history to record the visit.

So, the assets are not loaded on each visit. Fast. That's why document ready won't bind on all events, unless all listeners are targeted under body or document (eg `$("body").on("click","selector",function()...` instead of `$("selector").on('click', function()...`

Comment: can you explain why? I'm new to this stuff!

Comment: actually I just tried this, the same problem persists.

Comment: sorry, it is meant to be load, not visit.  check the updated version

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because some of the key events in older version of turbolinks is not compatible with the new turbolinks 5.

I suggested download the `gem jquery-turbolinks`  make sure to require to `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
......
```

and the compatibility script .You can find the script [here](https://github.com/mrvncaragay/HyraV2/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/compatibility.coffee) just create a `compatibility.coffee` under `assets/javascripts`

This will let you use the old syntax. `$(document).ready...`